# I am installing a ceiling fan with remote. I've connected the black and white wires but mounting brkt has grn/yell ground wire. What do I connect it?

Tags: ceiling-fan, installation

I need to know what I need to connect the green/yellow wire to. There is no box in the ceiling to ground it to. Please help. I can email or text pictures if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your pictures to [imgur](https://imgur.com) then post a link to them here and we can edit them into the post, or simply hit [edit] on your post (it's at the bottom left), then use the "mountain and sun" button in the editor to add them

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install a fan rated box in the ceiling and connect the cable/BX to the box with the appropriate connectors. If NB cable with a neutral, connect the neutral to the box and then to the fan bracket. If BX, then the metal sheathing should be grounded and will ground the box when connected to it. If there is no ground then just leave the green/yellow wire unconnected and stuffed into the box.